# saving background color of tableview cell

Tags: swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I did some research but a little confused as to how to solve this problem. I have a tableview whose cells have a button in it. When the user clicks the button the background of the cell changes. Now I was to save that background color so when the user starts the app up they are the color they selected. I believe the best way to do this is with nsuserdefaults but not 100% sure. If thats  the case do I set up a dictionary for this? If someone can steer me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is save the color *in the data model*, because otherwise the colors will become messed up as soon as the user scrolls and the cells are reused. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` must be rewritten to assign the correct background color to every cell it is asked for.

The second thing to do is think about *how* the color is to be saved. For example, if it's just a choice between two known colors, then you can save this as a number. But if it could be any color, then of course you need an actual color value.

Finally, yes, you can save the data model or any part of it in user defaults. But a color cannot be saved in user defaults until you archive it as an NSData (not hard).

Comment: if I update y dictionary in cellForRowAtIndexPath will it still populate because that method will have already been called and won't update?

Comment: obviously you don't change the model _in_ `cellForRow`. You change the model when "the user clicks the button [and] the background of the cell changes".